# Artifact deployed successfully on Wildfly 27.0.1, but URL is inaccessible

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

The problem is exactly what the title suggests. I am fairly new to JavaEE / JakartaEE development and I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

[image: artifact deployed successfully]

But, upon accessing the URL above, I get 'refused to connect' error:

[image]

Please help.

**Edit:**
This is the only error that is printed on console:

```
Aug 28, 2023 8:27:02 AM org.jboss.logmanager.JBossLoggerFinder getLogger
ERROR: The LogManager accessed before the "java.util.logging.manager" system property was set to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager". Results may be unexpected.
```

And, here are my dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Which URL is inaccessible? What client are you using? What's the actual error message?

Comment: @tgdavies 

 Which URL is inaccessible --> The one mentioned in the image '`http://localhost:8110/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT/`'

What client are you using? --> Wdym? I am using IntelliJ and any browser that is available on my system (chrome, firefox)

What's the actual error message? --> Only the one mentioned above. No other error is printed on console

Comment: By "client" I mean the piece of software which is making the request to that URL, presumably chrome. What component do you have in your project which you expect to respond to that request?

Comment: Could you post the message from undertow ? 8110 is not the standard port. I don't know about Intellij but this seems strange

Comment: Default port is 8080. Did you really explicitly change it to 8110 in WildFly's XML configuration file? The way how you asked the question strongly suggests that you didn't. Edit the URL in browser's address bar to use port 8080 instead of 8110. If that loads fine then IntelliJ config is wrong. And you need to take a step back to look why exactly it's using 8110. Was that told to you in some low quality tutorial? In that case you really need to abandon it and get yourself an authoritative book before you find yourself in a downward spiral of confusion and bad teachings/learnings/practices.

Comment: Hi @BalusC Thanks a lot! I didn't know all of this. I just typed 8080 in the browser and everything works! I am now able to access all the URLs.

As you guessed correctly, I did not explicitly change it in the configuration file. Apparently, for Wildfly, specifying the URL in IntelliJ configuration (as shown in the image) has absolutely no effect! Do you know if it is a bug in IntelliJ or is its purpose different? I do the same while using Tomcat and the app always uses the specified URL.

It was not told to me in any tutorial.

And yes, I will find myself a good book! :)

Comment: @BalusC Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it and mark it as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default port of a stock WildFly instance is 8080 (like as many other Jakarta EE application servers), but the 'URL' entry in 'Open browser' section of your IntelliJ Server config specifies 8110. This doesn't match. You need to edit the 'URL' entry to use port number 8080:

> http://localhost:8080/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

This specific config entry knows really nothing about the actual server being used. It is basically a free-entry setting which tells IntelliJ which webbrowser to launch and which URL to open once the deployment is successful. It's a free-entry because there may be a proxy server or hosts file configuration at the same machine beyond the control of the IDE which further changes the final hostname and/or port and/or even the context path to reach the deployment.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks for this insight, shows how less we should assume and how much important reading the intellij / wildfly documentation is.